# Ошибка при попытке получить текст Button в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно получить текст, находящийся внутри кнопки в Unity. Движок выдает NullReferenceException.Что я делаю не так?
Вот код метода целиком

```
public void BuyThing(GameObject panel, Thing thing)
{
    Button button = panel.GetComponent<Button>();
    string costText = button.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text;
    
    var child = panel.transform.GetChild(2);
    string incomeText = child.GetComponent<TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI>().text;

    Debug.Log(incomeText);
    Debug.Log(costText);
}
```

GetComponent достает кнопку, я проверял. Ошибка именно в следующей строке. Я пробовал вместо Text - TextMeshProUGUI, тоже не помогает.

Вот иерархия в Unity.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

**transform.GetChild(int)** возвращает один из дочерних объектов родителя по индексу. Как и в массиве, индекс начинается с нуля.
По вашему второму скриншоту видно, что у кнопки есть только один дочерний объект, соответственно, чтобы его получить, в вашем случае нужно заменить индекс "2" на "0".

```
var child = panel.transform.GetChild(0);
```